# How can I copy a cookie from one machine to another?

Tags: windows, firefox, cookies

I am unable to login to certain websites (such as StackOverflow) because the login URL is getting blocked (not the whole website) via a firewall.

Is it possible to copy the cookie file from another computer that is already logged into StackOverflow *to* this firewalled computer to trick the website that it is already authenticated and logged in?

Can this be done? If so, how?

Comment: Questions about the way the StackOverflow sites are working should be on meta.stackoverflow.com . Voting to migrate it there.

Comment: Gnoupi, I see your point, but the process could apply to any site, hence valid for SU? Mind, I don't have an answer!

Comment: @Gnoupi, although this question refers to stackoverflow, it is actually about moving cookies from computer-to-computer, which is completely independent of SOFU

Comment: I tend to agree with outsideblasts, though I would like Deostroll to make the question a little more readable...

Comment: @joshhunt and @outsideblasts - Sorry, I thought that it was depending on the site, so that it wouldn't apply to other sites. My knowledge in this matter is very thin ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox cookies are stored in the files cookies.sqlite and cookies.sqlite-journal in the folder

```
%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile>
```

where %APPDATA% is an environment variable that holds the path of the user's application data folder (which varies between Windows versions and languages), and `<profile>` is the name of the profile, which has a "random" component and ends with the profile name; if you don't have multiple Firefox profiles, there should be only one directory.

However, this means you cannot copy individual cookies, only the entire cookie database; and I am not 100% sure that simply copying the files will work.

Comment: [There are way to copy individual cookies](https://superuser.com/q/186609/494585), although it might not be so straightforward.