# How do I transfer / copy cookies from one browser to another or same browser from one machine to another?

Tags: browser, cookies

How do I copy the cookies from one browser in one machine to another? I want to retain the "user details" that the site maintains...

Comment: [StorageAce](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storageace/cpbgcbmddckpmhfbdckeolkkhkjjmplo) chrome extension provides **quick filters** and functionalities for **copy/export in different formats**.

Answer (score 8):

In Opera browser: Tools->Advanced->Cookies...

In Google Chrome browser:

Install Extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg and then you can add, delete, and edit your cookies.

To hand over cookies from one browser to another you most likely will have to copy-paste cookie's properties.

Comment: This works if you have just a handful of cookies, but it requires manually copy-and-past for each one. Definitely not a good option if you have lots of cookies to copy. See my answer below for a better option when using Chrome.

Comment: Will it work if I have Opera on my machine and Chrome on another?

Comment: @Scott the cookie is one by one. Nothing in bulk

Comment: For anyone still looking, this extension is able to export and import _all_ the cookies at once, allowing you to move to another machine https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/exp-cookies-tool/necipeebkikcoingolmohfaeckegimid

Answer (score 7):

**Option 1:** Use [Cookie Editor](http://www.hotcleaner.com/cookies.html) Chrome extension allows you to backup all cookies from one machine and import into a different one.

Steps to migrate your cookies:

1. Click on the extension you just installed
2. Mark all the cookies you want to export
3. Click the save icon at the bottom
4. Enter the encryption password
5. Hit the "Save" button that will appear, and store the file in a known location on your computer
6. Transfer the file, and just reverse the steps on the destination computer, clicking on Import

Now you have your cookies on a new computer.

Note that the extension only handles a few hundred cookies each time, so if you have a large number of cookies, you won't be able to export all of them at the same time.

**Option 2**: use the [default sync functionality](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/185277) in Google Chrome. It has the additional advantage of keeping not only cookies in sync, but also bookmarks, configuration, and even extensions (on the desktop).

You can also set an encryption password for your data.

Comment: I don't think the Chrome Sync function includes cookies.  Pretty much everything except cookies.

Answer (score 6):

If you're willing to edit some JavaScript code, you can manually import cookies into Chrome with a custom extension, using the [`chrome.cookies.set()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#method-set) API.

Since you specify the cookie data manually, this lets you import from any source into Chrome. (I used it to transfer cookies from Safari to Chrome.)

1. Create a folder for your extension. Add a file named `manifest.json` with the following contents, and **edit to specify which site's cookies you want to change** (the extension need to be given permission on those sites):

   ```
   {
       "name": "CookieImport",
       "version": "0.0.0",
       "permissions": [
           "cookies",
           "*://*.the-site-whose-cookies-you-want-to-change.com/*"
       ],
       "options_page": "options.html",
       "manifest_version": 2
   }
   ```
2. Add a file named `options.html` with the following. This simply loads the script we're going to create below.

   ```html
   <!doctype html>
   <html>
     <head></head>
     <body>
       <script src="options.js"></script>
     </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. Finally create `options.js` with this code, and **edit the beginning of this script to include the cookies you want to import**:

   ```js
   const allCookies = [
       {
           url: "https://www.example.com",
           name: "__foo",
           value: "bar",
           domain: ".example.com",
           expirationDate: Date.parse("8/19/2021, 8:16:03 PM"),
           // see all possible fields at:
           // https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#method-set
       },
       // ... more cookies here
   ];

   const button = document.createElement("button");
   button.type = "button";
   document.body.appendChild(button);
   button.textContent = "Import Cookies";
   button.addEventListener("click", () => {
       for (const c of allCookies) {
           chrome.cookies.set(c, (res) => {
               console.log("set", c, res || chrome.runtime.lastError);
           });
       }
   });
   ```
4. Install the extension via the **Load Unpacked** button as explained in this tutorial: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted#manifest
5. Click the extension's icon and select Options to open the page we created.
   [image: extension menu]
6. Finally, click the "Import Cookies" button to run the script.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to copy my Instagram session to another browser. So I went this way successfully.

### On the source browser

1. Hit <kbd>F12</kbd> / go to Dev Tools
2. Go to the network tab
3. Reload the page / hit <kbd>F5</kbd>
4. Scroll up to the very first entry (document http/200)
5. Click it and go to the headers tab
6. Find the cookie header and right click / copy value

### On the target browser

1. Go the other browser and hit <kbd>F12</kbd> / go to Dev Tools
2. Go to the console
3. Type `''.split(';').forEach(c => document.cookie=c);`
4. Paste your cookie value between the single(!) quotes and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
5. Reload the page / hit <kbd>F5</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Internet Explorer use the Import/Export funtion in the
File Menu. Other Browsers have similar functions, check the help files.

**How to import cookies in IE of computer A to IE of computer B**

> - In computer A start up IE.
> - Click on File...Import and Export...
> - In the Wizard window click on Next. Highlight Export Cookies. click on
>     Next.
> - Click on Export to a file.
> - In the window below you can accept the default location of the file
> - cookies.txt or choose your own location using Browse.
> - Now copy that cookies.txt file USB minidrive (whatever).
> - Put the USB minidrive in computer B.
> - Either copy cookies.txt to computer B hard drive or just leave it on the
>     minidrive.
> - In computer B start up IE. Click on File...Import and Export....in the
>     Wizard window
> - click on Next. Highlight Import Cookies. Click on Next.
> - Click on Import from a file. In the window below use Browse to find the
>     cookies.txt file minidrive or on your
>     hard drive if you copied it there.
>     Highlight it. Click on Next.
> - Click on Finish.

Resource from  [here](http://www.technologyquestions.com/technology/windows-xp/58729-how-can-i-copy-cookies-computer-b-compter.html)

Comment: And Yeah you can import/export cookies from other browsers in a similar fashion

Answer (score 1):

For browser to browser, if you're using Firefox/IE you can use IE Tab Plus, this will seamlessly transfer cookies to IE when launched with the add-on.

Comment: and across machines?

Comment: @Jeff F. Esta se referindo a Favoritos...