# Export/Import of cookies in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, internet-explorer-11

There is a lot of Q and A about this on earlier versions of Internet Explorer (ex: [How do I transfer / copy cookies from one browser to another or same browser from one machine to another?](https://superuser.com/q/186609/26811)) but there seems to be no info on how to do it on IE11. And I have no `File`-menue on my browser.

Any suggestions would help. Thanks!

Comment: I have never heard of any browser supporting the capability to export a cookie.  What makes you think its possible to do this in IE?

Comment: This for example: http://superuser.com/a/186620/26811

Comment: Press Alt key to [show the menu bar](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/show-the-menu-bar-in-internet-explorer) in IE11.